# Permitiendo cambiar contraseña

Tags: laravel-5

Aun sigo teniendo problemas al permitir cambiar la contraseña.
He descubierto que se suponia que debo usar la siguiente vista, llamada reset.blade.php (hice unos pequeños cambios para pasarla al español, pero solo se ha cambiado textos):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Cambiar Contraseña</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Correo electronico</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Contraseña</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Confirmar Contraseña</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password_confirmation" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Cambiar Contraseña
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Para acceder a esta vista, he modificado el formulario de login para incluirlo:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Inicie sesión</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" novalidate>
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Correo Electronico</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Contraseña</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Recordarme
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Ingresar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <center>
                            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                ¿Olvidaste la contraseña?
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/cambiar_clave') }}">
                                ¿Deseas cambiar la contraseña?
                            </a>
                        </center>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Esta es la ruta en web.php:

```
Route::get('/cambiar_clave','UserController@clambiado');
```

Y esta es la función:

```
public function clambiado(){
    return view('auth.passwords.reset');
}
```

Pero me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que se supone que es $token?

Comment: Intenta remover esta linea en tu primera vista de la pregunta: <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}"> ya con la linea de arriba @csrf ya incluyes en tu formulario el campo oculto para el token

Answer (score 1):

1. La vista que estás intentando usar está pensada para restablecer una contraseña a partir de una petición de restablecerla
2. Dicha petición se genera desde la vista para restablecer la clave a la que se accede mediante la opción *"¿Olvidaste la contraseña?"*
3. Al pedir un restablecimiento de la clave, se nos manda un correo electrónico con un enlace único que lleva un `token` que permite identificar la cuenta de la cual queremos cambiar la clave. Esto se hace así para asegurarnos que quien quiere cambiar la clave es el poseedor de la cuenta de correo asociada
4. Si tú te saltas ese procedimiento, no tienes ningún `token` generado y vas a permitir que cualquiera, introduciendo un correo electrónico al azar, pueda cambiar la clave si ese correo está registrado, lo cual supone un agujero de seguridad enorme

Mi consejo es: usa tanto las vistas como los controladores que trae Laravel al generarlos con `php artisan make:auth` y solo modifica aquello que tenga sentido como traducciones de textos, o eliminar la opción de registro, si no la quieres habilitar

Para que un usuario cambie su clave, se puede hacer si está logueado o, si no se puede loguear porque no recuerda su clave, mediante la opción de restablecer contraseña, nunca dejando que la cambie directamente solo con su dirección de correo electrónico

Comment: Es decir, que es posible estar logueado y cambiar contraseña. ¿Pero como?

Comment: Es una cuestión de seguridad, de lógica, no tiene que ver con que puedas hacerlo con el framework o no. Simplemente es un update del usuario del campo password usando la encriptación que corresponda. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de controlador que hace precisamente eso: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing

Comment: Lo que me estas enseñando es respecto a la función para que una vez rellenado el formulario cambie la contraseña, pero yo lo que busco es un formulario para modificar la contraseña.

Comment: Ok. Yo usaría el mismo formulario en el que restableces la clave pero tendrías que hacer algunos ajustes, tales como cambiar el action del formulario, quitar el campo del email y también quitar la parte del token

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre una solución, aunque es algo estrafalaria.
Como tenia otros formularios para cambiar otras variables, las he fusionado en una sola:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Cambie aquí algunos de los datos de su cuenta.</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="cambiar_datos" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="foto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nueva foto de perfil</label>

                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <input id="foto" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('foto') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="foto" value="{{ old('foto') }}" />

                                    @if ($errors->has('foto'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('foto') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="telefono" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nuevo telefono</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="telefono" type="number" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('telefono') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="telefono" value="{{auth()->user()->telefono}}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('telefono'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('telefono') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="vehiculo" class="col-md-6 col-form-label text-md-right">¿Sigues teniendo vehículo?</label>
                                Si<input type="radio" name="vehiculo" value=1 {{auth()->user()->vehiculo==true ? 'checked' : ''}}/>
                                No<input type="radio" name="vehiculo" value=0 {{auth()->user()->vehiculo==false ? 'checked' : ''}}/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="campo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nueva contraseña</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="campo" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('campo') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="campo" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('campo'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('campo') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="campo-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Confirmar la nueva contraseña</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="campo-confirm" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('campo_confirmation') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="campo_confirmation" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('campo_confirmation'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('campo_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Confirmar cambios
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Ahora ya no aparece el misterioso error del texto en la contraseña.